# iPad Video with Transparency

Tags: objective-c, ipad, video, ios4, ios

is it possible to have a QuickTime video with alpha layer (transparency) play on top of a static dynamic background `UIView` (i.e. a view that changes occasionally) on the iPad?

**Thanks!**

Comment: I've not seen a solution to this anywhere. I'd like to layer a video over a portion of the interface. or at the least over a custom colored background.

Comment: Creating a transparent video layer can be achieved using QuickTime Pro: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=42599. I am not sure that the transparency will hold on an iOS device.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this? Where you able to play transparente video on iOS?

Comment: with bink video formate u can easily do...Also that bink library is available for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clear up the misinformation, you can't use a video with an alpha channel using the built in video logic in iOS. You can create a Quicktime movie encoded with the Animation codec and load the video into a view or layer using AVAnimator. What you can't do is create a H264 video with an alpha channel, that is simply is not supported by iOS.

[display movies with an alpha channel under iOS](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html)

Comment: [AVAnimator](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/) works best for this use case. It requires transcoding to APNG or their own format, but it's fast enough for smooth 30fps video w/alpha.

Comment: MoDJ's library needs a commercial license, has rather involved extra steps and has not that great performance (extracting 7z, extra video track, etc)

Here is a solution using free open source library, works entirely on the GPU (great performance even with big videos) and requires only two things:
 - Transparent image (either PNG or in code)
 - Instead of a transparent, a green background for the video

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244347/video-with-gpuimagechromakeyfilter-has-tint-when-played-in-transparent-gpuimagev/33255662

Comment: Mopt, you are certainly entitled to your opinion on which open source license you like the best. But being critical of my software on technical grounds is nonsense. This other third party library you suggest is a different implementation, but it is not clearly better. For one thing, there is the problem of green or near green colors when processing green screen video (think of a weatherman with a shirt that goes see through). Also, the library you suggest does not handle seamless looping and it does not handle sync of video to audio. In addition, it is limited to 4 decoding streams at a time.

Comment: A point by point comparison that shows actual results from a green screen vs alpha channel comparison is available. http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/

Comment: I also just added a new example project that shows an alpha channel render that does 30 FPS RGB+Alpha rendering using the iOS h264 hardware and OpenGL. https://github.com/mdejong/H264AlphaPlayer

Answer (score 1):

[MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a backgroundView property.  The docs state:

> This view provides the backing content, on top of which the movie content is displayed. You can add subviews to the background view if you want to display custom background content.

I haven't tried it, but if the video content itself has alpha, it sounds like this view should show up.  If you set that view to clear, it may just work...

Answer (score 0):

first your video needs transparency: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=42599

IMHO: I think the videocomponent has a solid background color (black) you will have to set it to `[UIColor clearColor]` You have to try, im not sure if that works.

cheers endo

Answer (score 0):

You could have a normal video and reduce the alpha of the presenting view.  This can be done using an `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` by adding the `AVPlayerLayer` to a `UIView` and setting the alpha of the `UIView`.  Something like:

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
self.playerLayer.frame = view.bounds;
...etc...
self.playerView.alpha = 0.3;
[self.playerView.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
```

I haven't tried this with the alpha channel in the video itself, but AVPlayerLayer should work for that as well.

Comment: not clear - I have a video with alpha channel. I want to overlay that video on my background (let's say pink color). I should reduce alpha of the background view then?..

Comment: If the alpha information is encoded in the video, you should not need to reduce the alpha in any of the views (either the UIView holding the AVPlayerLayer or any UIViews beneath).  Only reduce the alpha of the UIView presenting the AVPlayerLayer if the alpha info is not encoded in the video itself.

Comment: The original poster is asking about a video with an alpha channel which controls alpha on a pixel by pixel basis which is useful for overlays. Setting the alpha for all pixels in a video is not equivalent solution and does not address the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can make videos transparent , while playing the video adjust the alpha of view from 0.0 to 1.0. for eg 0.50.  After playing the vido change the alpha of view to 1.0.