# Does AVFoundation (OS X) support transparent playback of videos with alpha channel?

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation

Is there a way of playing back video files that include an alpha channel using `AVFoundation`? I would like to add an `AVPlayerLayer` as a sublayer to my layer tree preserving transparency so it works like as an overlay.

Or is it alternatively possible to use a second greyscale video as an alpha mask for the main movie?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AVFoundation on OS X is only able to play h.264. If you to get it working with older Quicktime movies that contain an alpha channel then it might be possible. A short term fix would be to use a series of PNG images instead of a movie, but that would not involve AVFoundation. You could also read about my library that could be used for this kind of this at [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660482/ipad-video-with-transparency/12128695#12128695). The answer is talking about iOS, but the library could be used with either iOS or OS X.